# Recommendations for a clean vanilla machine install Ubuntu LAMP setup with python on Amazon EC2

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm setting up a ubuntu LAMP server on EC2, can anyone recommend a simple machine image

Requirements:
Ubuntu Server
LAMP
Python, Python-imaging ( can self install )

The server is for testing a python application. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to foot the bill: https://10.cloud.ubuntu.com/faq/

They've got a link to the images they registered with Amazon.

Comment: Thanks, I've got access to EC2 already. lots of options, just looking for a recommendation clean vanilla  install

Comment: Ubuntu folks have images hosted here http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/, apparently it's even really easy to install them onto ec2.